# Handlebars JS is processing HTML as String

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am providing html content as string to a handlebars variable with double curly braces {{ }}, expecting it to get processed as html but ended up seeing raw html codes. below is my implementation. please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="temp">
        <div>
            hey there... {{ somedata }}
        </div>
    </script>

    <div id="thedata"></div>

    <script src="handlebar.js"></script>
    <script>
        let rawTemplate = document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
        let compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
        let somedata = "<span>hello there</span>"
        let handlebarJsonData = {
            somedata: somedata,
        };
        let htmlData = compiledTemplate(handlebarJsonData);
        document.getElementById("thedata").innerHTML = htmlData;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result that i am getting is

> hey there... `<span>hello there</span>`

but, i wanted

> hey there... hello there

Please help

Comment: Use `{{{somedata}}}` instead of `{{somedata}}`.

Comment: thanks a lot man. it worked. cheers